# symfony2 WebTestCase selecting option by index

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing

I'm writing an WebTestCase for submitting a Form in symfony2's WebTestCase class, and I'd like to know if it's possible to select a box option by index.

It works to select a special option by its value (select box with name "branch", option with value "test" is selected in the following example):

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('submit')->form();
$form["branch"]->select('test');
$client->submit($form);
```

In my case I'd like to select second option of the select box, without knowing its value.

Thank you!
Matthias

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
$values = $form['branch']->availableOptionValues();
$form['branch']->select($values[1]);
```